# WordPress почему не меняется виджет поиска после того как я его изменил в хуке get_search_form?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот код:

```
add_filter( 'get_search_form', function ( $form ) {

$form = '
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Запрос для поиска:</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Найти" />
</form>';

$form = '
<div class="widget widget_search">
    <form id="searchform" method="get" role="search" action="' . home_url('/blog/') .'">
        <input class="text-search" type="text" onfocus="" placeholder="Search here..." value="' . get_search_query() . '">
        <input type="submit" class="submit-search" value="">
    </form>
</div>';

return $form; } );
```

Но в сайдбаре ничего не меняется, если я просто вызову этот виджет в коде через `get_search_form()`
То тогда уже появляется кастомизированная форма поиска, но мне нужно чтобы форма была такой в сайдбаре

Answer (score 4):

после того как в WordPress добавили редактор блоков в виджеты вы больше не можете изменить виджет поиска через фильтр `get_search_form`, потому что для нового редактора виджетов используются виджеты блоков.

Вы можете изменить форму поиска использую фильтры для создания блоков

```
add_filter( 'pre_render_block', function( $pre_render_block, $args ) {
    if ( $args['blockName'] !== 'core/search' ) {
        return;
    }

    $form = '<div class="widget widget_search">
            <form id="searchform" method="get" role="search" action="' . home_url('/blog/') .'">
                <input class="text-search" type="text" onfocus="" placeholder="Search here..." value="' . get_search_query() . '">
                <input type="submit" class="submit-search" value="">
            </form>
            </div>';

    return $form;
}, 10, 2 );
```